Community user cannot see data (of a particular Lookup field (Account)), but they have Read access on the Permission Set
In Salesforce, I go to CaseA, CustomLookupFieldA(Account)
As expected, it has a reference to another record
I log into Community as CommunityUserA, I go to CaseA, CustomLookupFieldA(Account) (on the Case Detail page).
The field is there, the reference is not.
CommunityUserA has a Permission Set with Read on Account (and FSL Read only on Name, Id, Number), and with Read on Case and FSL Read only on CustomLookupFieldA(Account).
Please help me get data to Community.

Does the community user actually have access to the Account referenced in the custom lookup field? If it isn't their own Account, how are you sharing that with them?

Ah, sharing rules. Thanks. Looking into it.

Thanks Callumn MacErlich!
I did a Criteria based Sharing Rule on Account
Share Account records of a certain Type with Public Group: PublicGroupA (which CommunityUserA already belongs to).
